# Style Sub routine fails when workbook protected

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, password-protection

I am really struggling with trying to understand why a sub routine to set styles will not work if the workbook has been protected. I have tried to unlock the specific page before the sub routine but this fails. I have tried locking the Workbook with **UserInterFaceOnly:=True**, and this didn't work either!

I have this routine set for when the Workbook is opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        ws.Protect Password:="Password", _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next ws

    Sheets("Menu").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
End Sub
```

The Sub routine I have is this

```
Sub InputStyleRestore()
  With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Input")
    .Interior.Color = 10079487
    .Font.Color = -9027777
    
  End With
End Sub
```

When the Workbook is locked I get a *"Run-Time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined Error"* and the line  `.Interior.Color = 10079487` is highlighted.

The start of the routine where I want the page to be temporarily unlocked starts like this

```
Sub PartialPrintFamForm()



Dim FTW As Long
Dim myVariable As Long
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
Dim OutlApp As Object

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
    InputStyleRestore
' Employee Name as Title
  Title = Range("E21")

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Caledonian Road Fam Form" Then
        myVariable = Sheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form").Range("R21").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form").Range("O21").Value, Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1:B1000"), 0)
        FTW = Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Cells(FTW, 25) = myVariable
        MsgBox "The First page only will now print out for you."
        InputStyleClear
```

Is there another method I am unaware of that will get the routine to work with the workbook locked, as it works fine when unlocked manually.

Here is the InputStyleClear Sub routine

```
Sub InputStyleClear()


        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        
  
    With ActiveSheet.Name
            .Unprotect Password:="Pampigny", _
                DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _
                Scenarios:=False, UserInterFaceOnly:=False
             
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.Styles("Input")
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
            
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.Name
        
                .Protect Password:="Pampigny", _
                DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    End With

                   
  
        'Allow Computer Screen to refresh (not necessary in most cases)
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** This solution explains the structure and behaviour of workbook styles and why the need to unprotect all sheets in order to modify any style. However, in order to avoid the need to constantly modify the Workbook Styles, I suggest the creation of two Styles, something like `InputOn` & `InputOff`, and apply them as required. This will eliminate the need to modify the styles and the requirement to unprotect and protect all worksheets.

---

Few points to highlight:

1. Mention of `Workbook` protection, however the code published does not contain any instance of `Workbook.Protect` instead the protection applied affects only `Worksheets`
2. The `Workbook_Open` event attempts to protect all worksheets applying the `UserInterFaceOnly` property, however it tries to apply this property to `worksheets` already protected, as such it fails to activate the property. The `Worksheets` must be unprotected first, then protected including the property `UserInterFaceOnly=TRUE` to be effective.
3. The [Style object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.style) is a member of the `Styles object` and although located at `Workbook` level, once a `Worksheet` is protected the entire `Styles collection` is protected as well. Therefore to perform modifications to any `Style` *all* `Worksheets` must be unprotected even if the `Style` to be modified is not used in any of the `Worksheets`.

Suggest to apply these changes to your procedures:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Rem Using Sheet instead of Worksheet to care for Charts in the workbook if any
Dim Sht As Object
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Sht In .Sheets
            With Sht
                .Unprotect Password:="Password"
                .Protect Password:="Password", _
                    DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                    Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        End With: Next
    
        With .Sheets("Menu")
            Activate
            Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
    
    End With: End With

    End Sub
```

In the procedure `PartialPrintFamForm` replace these lines:

```
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
  InputStyleRestore
```

with these:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    For Each Sht In .Sheets
        Sht.Unprotect Password:="Password"
Next: End With

InputStyleRestore

With ThisWorkbook
    For Each Sht In .Sheets
        With Sht
            .Protect Password:="Password", _
                DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End With: Next: End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly! I did come across a couple of things I needed to do i.e. I had to use the same formula to activate _InputStyleClear_ sub routine.

Comment: If `InputStyleClear` modifies any `Workbook.Style` then it's the same situation affecting `InputStyleRestore`, therefore same method needs to be applied. Please, let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: I have encountered a problem with `InputStyleClear`. When it unlocks every page, it changes the ActiveSheet focus so that it is not longer the one I started with. The idea is to remove the style aspect before creating pdf's and emails, and printing a hard copy. There are 17 different pages that the user could choose, so I am trying to get the sub routine `InputStyleClear` to unlock the active sheet only, or if that is not possible, to unlock everything, then focus on the original active sheet

Comment: The procedure `InputStyleClear`, as published, does not unlock every page. Nevertheless, the original problem stated in this question has been solved. Now the new problem might have to do with how the solution was implemented, as it seems that some modifications to other procedures in your project were not conducted. Nevertheless that seems to belong to another question, therefore I suggest to please gather all relevant data and create a new question stating the new problem.

Comment: On a side note perhaps instead of constantly modifying the styles, I suggest to create two styles, something like `InputOn` & `InputOff` and apply them as required, that way you don't have to constantly modify the workbook style, therefore no need to keep unprotecting and protecting all worksheets.